# APScheduler resets after every deploy

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, apscheduler

I have a script which which when run adds rss feed parsing tasks to some celery queues. Now I have implemented apscheduler to run the script every 2 hours to get new data from the feeds.

My implementation looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import atexit
import logging
import os
from logging import getLogger

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


logger = getLogger('scheduled_parser')
PARSER_SCHEDULER = 'parser_scheduler'


def main():
   scheduler = BlockingScheduler(job_defaults={'coalesce': True})
   scheduler.add_jobstore('sqlalchemy',alias='scheduler_config', url=os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"))
   scheduler.add_job(run_parser, 'interval', seconds=int(os.environ.get("SCHEDULER_RUN_FREQUENCY")),
                     id=PARSER_SCHEDULER, replace_existing=True)
   scheduler.start()
   atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())

def run_parser():
   < code to add items to queues>

if __name__ == "__main__":
   logging.basicConfig()
   logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   main()
```

My code is deployed on heroku and I have following in my procfile

```
clock: python scheduled_parser
<celery worker processes>
```

I am having following issues:

1. I am storing the scheduler job in persistant storage and I can even see it in my db, but when I do scheduler.get_job(PARSER_SCHEDULER,'scheduler_config')  I get None
2. Whenever I deploy on heroku, I think the next run is being updated. For example if parser is set to run every 2 hours and next run going to be at 4:00pm and if I deploy on Heroku at 3:00pm then my next run happens at 5:00pm instead of 4:00pm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your issue #1, but I think issue #2 is that on every deploy, this line is going to replace the job, thus resetting the schedule:

```
   scheduler.add_job(run_parser, 'interval', seconds=int(os.environ.get("SCHEDULER_RUN_FREQUENCY")),
                 id=PARSER_SCHEDULER, replace_existing=True)
```